RestEasy failed to parse eml file
In my java jboss project, I use resteasy api to support uploading files, it works fine until someone uploaded an .eml file and triggered NPE.
A more detailed description of the problem is here: https://issues.redhat.com/browse/RESTEASY-1255
The version of Resteasy that I'm using is 3.0.24.final.
The solution I tried:
As I navigated through the related tickets of RESTEASY-1255, I found its related ticket https://issues.redhat.com/browse/RESTEASY-754, indicating the issue is resolved in version 4.0.0.final
so I upgraded resteasy-multipart-provider to 4.0.0.final
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.0.CR1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

but the problem remains.
I'm very unfamiliar with jboss or resteasy.
Could anyone point me the direction to any possible solution? A detailed instruction would be much appreciated!
Here is the snippet of my code:
Controller interface
import org.jboss.resteasy.annotations.providers.multipart.MultipartForm; 
import org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartFormDataInput;     
    
    @POST     
    @GZIP     
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)     
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)     
    @Path("/upload")     
    public Response uploadSomeDocument(@MultipartForm MultipartFormDataInput input);  

Controller interface Implementation
import org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.InputPart;
import org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartFormDataInput;

@Override
public Response uploadSomeDocument(MultipartFormDataInput input) {
    Map<String, List<InputPart>> formDataMap = input.getFormDataMap();
    List<InputPart> inputParts = formDataMap.get("file");
    // here the inputStream is null
    InputStream inputStream = inputPart.getBody(InputStream.class, null);
    // therefore trigger NPE in this step   
    byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);  
    // operation on bytes
}

pom.xml
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.bom</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-eap-javaee7-with-tools</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.0.GA</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final-redhat-3</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-jaxrs-api_2.0_spec</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


  </dependencies>

stack trace
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:2314) [commons-io-2.6.jar:2.6]
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:2270) [commons-io-2.6.jar:2.6]
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:2291) [commons-io-2.6.jar:2.6]
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:2246) [commons-io-2.6.jar:2.6]
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(IOUtils.java:765) [commons-io-2.6.jar:2.6]
    at com.xxx.repository.SOUploadFileRepository.write(SOUploadFileRepository.java:64) [data-scx-2.0.188-SNAPSHOT.jar:]
    at com.xxx.so.SalesOrderServiceImpl.uploadCustomerPoDocument(SalesOrderServiceImpl.java:2179) [data-scx-2.0.188-SNAPSHOT.jar:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_362]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_362]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_362]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) [rt.jar:1.8.0_362]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:140) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.24.Final-redhat-1.jar:3.0.24.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:295) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.24.Final-redhat-1.jar:3.0.24.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:249) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.24.Final-redhat-1.jar:3.0.24.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:236) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.24.Final-redhat-1.jar:3.0.24.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:406) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.24.Final-redhat-1.jar:3.0.24.Final-redhat-1]
    ... 43 more

run environment
It's packed as a war file and run under JBoss EAP 7.1

Is there options to upgrade JBoss EAP to 7.4?

@JamesR.Perkins Thanks for the reply. I tried upgrading to 7.4 and the issue remains, the resteasy verison is 3.15.1.final

I"m not sure what is null, but it's coming from com.nfsmith.repository.SOUploadFileRepository.write(SOUploadFileRepository.java:64) [data-scx-2.0.188-SNAPSHOT.jar:].
